# Can a React selector return a specific type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, selector

I'm new to both React & Typescript, and trying to figure out if a selector can return a custom type.

This is a basic selector that returns a user of type `Map<string, any>`:

***selectors/user.ts***

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';
import { TypedMap } from 'reducers';
import { User } from 'types/api';

const rawSelectUser = (state: TypedMap) => state.get('session');
const selectUser = () =>
    createSelector(
        rawSelectUser,
        substate => substate.get('user')
    );

export default selectUser;
```

I'm wondering if I could get it to return a type `User` that I'm using elsewhere in my app:

***types/api.ts***

```
export class User implements Serializable<User> {
    id!: number;
    firstName!: string;
    lastName!: string;
    name!: string;
    email!: string;
    isActive!: boolean;
    role!: UserRole;
    metadata?: any;
}
```

Ultimately, I want my .tsx files to use my User type from `types/api.ts`. But this code currently produces the error below:

***index.tsx***

```
...

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector<TypedMap, LoginProps, User>({
    user: selectUser()
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch<AnyAction>) =>
    bindActionCreators(
        {
            postLogin,
            checkUserPresent
        },
        dispatch
    );

const withConnect = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
);

const themedComponent = withTheme(withStyles(styles)(Login));
export default compose(withConnect)(themedComponent);

mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch<AnyAction>) =>
```

...generates this error:

```
index.js:1437 /Users/username/sites/my-ui/src/containers/Login/index.tsx
TypeScript error in /Users/username/sites/my-ui/src/containers/Login/index.tsx(151,5):
Argument of type '{ user: OutputSelector<TypedMap, any, (res: Map<string, any>) => any>; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ id: ParametricSelector<TypedMap, LoginProps, number>; firstName: ParametricSelector<TypedMap, LoginProps, string>; lastName: ParametricSelector<TypedMap, LoginProps, string>; ... 6 more ...; fromState: ParametricSelector<...>; }'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'user' does not exist in type '{ id: ParametricSelector<TypedMap, LoginProps, number>; firstName: ParametricSelector<TypedMap, LoginProps, string>; lastName: ParametricSelector<TypedMap, LoginProps, string>; ... 6 more ...; fromState: ParametricSelector<...>; }'.  TS2345

    149 | // }
    150 | const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector<TypedMap, LoginProps, User>({
  > 151 |     user: selectUser()
        |     ^
    152 | });
    153 | 
    154 | const
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const getSession = (state: TypedMap) => state.get('session');
const selectUser = createSelector(
  getSession,
  (session): User => session.get('user')
)
```

Note the type assertion on the second argument to `createSelector`

and

```
createStructuredSelector<TypedMap, LoginProps, { user: User }>
```

Comment: Thanks @Donovan. Unfortunately, that generates the same "Argument not assignable" error I posted at the end of my OP. Any ideas? My gut says it has something to do with the types for `createStructuredSelector()` or `createSelector()` or something..

Comment: @doub1ejack In my playground I was able to get it working through

1. Removing the outer function wrapping `selectUser`
2. Matching the shape of the object passed in to `createStructuredSelector` in the types `{ user: User }`. Post updated.